# c# How to make added text unchangable

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, textbox

I would like to ask if there is any way to not be able to change. I am not good enough to explain it properly so there is part of my code.

```
string[] row = { firstColumn, secondColumn + " KC", day + ". " 
                + month + ". " + year, fourthColumn + " KC" };
```

And I would like not to be able to change KC. I made my selection through row selection.

```
paymentRecordsTextBox.Text = row.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
```

And I don't want to change that "KC" part. I am using TextBox to change selected value.

I'am new to c# and I would like to know if there is easier way to make it.
If there was someone already asking similiar question I would be like to post link.

Comment: I'm sorry the question seems to be uncomplete & hard to understand. "I made my selection" => Which selection? What exactly is the context in which (or: because of which) you don't want s.th. to be changed?

Comment: Selection from DataGridView the row I want to change. When I select it it will take all items from that cell and I would like to pick only fourthColumn without " KC"..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I'm assuming you're using WinForms, pleas add a tag to your question)

I don't know if I understood you right, but you can use [MaskedTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.maskedtextbox.mask%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to edit your value, setting the mask to:

```
CCCCCCCCCC K\C
```

Where `'C'` at the start are any optional, non-control characters (the number of `'C'`s is the maximum length of your editable text).

The user will be able to only change the beginning of the string, the end (`" KC"`) will not be editable.